# Partial application of templates as concept evidence?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have this concept:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M>
struct monad {
    // M<A> pure(A a)
    // M<B> flatMap(M<A> ma, std::function<M<B> (A)> f) // typename B = std::invoke_result_t<F&, A const&>

    static constexpr bool is_instance = false;
};

template<template<typename> typename M> concept MonadPure = requires(blackbox::A a, blackbox::B b) {
    { monad<M>::pure(a) } -> std::same_as<M<blackbox::A>>;
    { monad<M>::pure(b) } -> std::same_as<M<blackbox::B>>;
};

template<template<typename> typename M> concept MonadFlatMap = requires(M<blackbox::A> ma,
                                                                        blackbox::F<blackbox::A, M<blackbox::B>> f) {
    { monad<M>::flatMap(ma, f) } -> std::same_as<M<blackbox::B>>;
};

template<template<typename> typename M> concept Monad = monad<M>::is_instance && MonadPure<M> && MonadFlatMap<M>;
```

And I want to implement its `struct monad` evidence for the `StateT` transformer:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M, typename S, typename A> using StateT =
M<std::function<M<std::pair<S, A>>(S)>>;
```

Since the below is not valid:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M, typename S>
requires Monad<M>
struct monad<template<typename A> StateT<M, S, A>> { // do stuff
```

I have to "partially apply" `StateT`:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M, typename S>
struct PartiallyAppliedStateT {
    template<typename A>
    struct _Apply {
        typedef StateT<M, S, A> type;
    };

    template<typename A>
    using Apply = typename _Apply<A>::type;
};

template<template<typename> typename M, typename S>
requires Monad<M>
struct monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<M, S>::Apply> { // do stuff
```

Yet, this leaves me with an error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class M> struct monad'
   57 |     struct monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<M, S>::Apply> {
      |                                                     ^
note:   expected a class template, got 'PartiallyAppliedStateT<M, S>::Apply'
```

How can I make a partial application a `class`, like I think G++ is asking? Or is there a better way to make a `StateT` monad?

G++ version 10.1.0 with `-std=c++20`.

---

After correcting the `monad` definition:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M, typename S>
requires Monad<M>
struct monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<M, S>::template Apply> {
```

I can describe a function like so:

```cpp
template<template<typename> typename M>
requires Monad<M>
StateT<M, long, long> nextLong() {
    return monad<M>::pure([](long seed) {
        long next = seed * 6364136223846793005L + 1442695040888963407L;
        return monad<M>::pure(std::make_pair(next, seed));
    });
}
```

Which represents getting an output from a Linear Congruential Generator. If we take the following definition for `Id`:

```cpp
template<typename A> using Id = A;
```

`Id`'s `pure` is just returning the passed in value, and `flatMap` is just applying a function to the value. It follows then that the following definition should be valid:

```cpp
StateT<Id, long, long> doubleXor = monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::flatMap(nextLong<Id>(), [](long value1) {
    return monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::flatMap(nextLong<Id>(), [value1](long value2) {
        return monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::pure(value1 ^ value2);
    });
});
```

The value `doubleXor` represents the operation of advancing the seed of our LCG twice and then XORing the two outputs. However, the compiler cannot find the `monad` instance we defined specifically above, only the default `monad` instance without the defined methods:

```
In function 'long int doThing()':
error: 'flatMap' is not a member of 'monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long int>::Apply>'
   95 |     StateT<Id, long, long> doubleXor = monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::flatMap(nextLong<Id>(), [](long value1) {
      |                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~
In lambda function:
error: 'flatMap' is not a member of 'monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long int>::Apply>'
   96 |         return monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::flatMap(nextLong<Id>(), [value1](long value2) {
      |                                                                         ^~~~~~~
In lambda function:
error: 'pure' is not a member of 'monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long int>::Apply>'
   97 |             return monad<PartiallyAppliedStateT<Id, long>::template Apply>::pure(value1 ^ value2);
      |                                                                             ^~~~
```

Comment: So you want to write a concept, that checks whether a template template parameter `M` is a monad for all types `A`? I don't think that is possible, since for that the compiler would have to check whether the requirements holds for all `A` and I do not think that that is feasible. What you could do is write a concept that takes three inputs `M`, `A` and `B` and checks if `M` is a monad for `A` and `B` (i.e. has a map `A -> M<A>` and map `(A -> B) -> (M<A> -> M<B>)`.

Comment: @n314159 It is not that (`M<A>` is a monad for all `A`), but rather that (`M` is a monad). The concepts for `MonadPure` and `MonadFlatMap` use a `blackbox` struct whose only purpose is to verify as best as possible that said monad operates on any C++ type. Nothing in `blackbox` has an inhabitant, i.e. there can never be a value of type `blackbox::A`/`B`/`F`. It is true that I am not able to constrain that `pure` is `a -> m a` and `flatMap` is `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, and that's what the `blackbox` type is for. I'd prefer to keep it `Monad<M>`.

Comment: How would you actually use `monad<M>`, assuming you got this to work?

Comment: You forgot `template` before `Apply` at the last line.

Comment: @Oliv That allows the definition to compile, but then it cannot find `monad<PartiallyAppliedState<Id, long>::template Apply>` when it should be used. `Id` has a tested and working `monad` instance. I will update my question now.

Comment: @Soren: "*but rather that (M is a monad)*" But what does that mean? What does it mean for a type to "be a monad"? Does that mean that you can use the type as a monad? What if a type can only be used as a monad for certain other types? Is it no longer a monad? The question itself doesn't make sense with C++ concepts; you need concepts based on your *uses* of the type. And the behavior you're looking for involves two types: the monad, and the type that the monad wraps. Both of which you will know when you are ready to use one.

Comment: @NicolBolas `M` is a _type constructor_. _Type constructors_ can be Monads. Most languages do not have the concept of Monads constrained to a category (a subset of types) for good reason. I already recognize that I am unable to qualify that a monad should work on all types. If I constrain a Monad at the template level to what it can flatMap over, any large monadic construction will require an incredibly annoying amount of `requires` clauses for each new type used. Additionally, it's much different from the definition and usage of `Monad` in other languages.

Comment: @NicolBolas Some examples: `std::option<int>` is not a type constructor, `std::option` is. `StateT<M, S, A>` is not a type constructor, `α => StateT<M, S, α>`/`StateT<M, S, *>` are. Type constructors can also take more than one argument or other type constructors as arguments, for example `std::pair<*, *>` or `StateT<*, S, A>` respectively.

Comment: @Soren: "*`std::option<int>` is not a type constructor, `std::option` is.*" But the code that needs to actually be constrained knows about both `std::option` and `int`, since it has to put those two together to do its job. So the constraint "Monad" is a constraint on not just the monadic template, but also on the type it is given. It's a binary constraint; you cannot constrain a template on *just* a monad, because at some point, you're going to *use* that monad with some type.

Comment: @NicolBolas The whole point of this project is to 1. abstract over behavior 2. avoid stacks upon stacks of `requires` clauses when I'm using many types.

Comment: @NicolBolas Again, I understand that I cannot express the constraint that a monad should work on all types. _Whether a monadic program works correctly is up to the library user defining the monad evidence_. Even in languages like Haskell, there's certain laws typeclasses have to follow. It's impossible to express those constraints even in Haskell, but whether the program works correctly is dependent on whether those laws are followed in the instance of the typeclass. I must be more lenient with C++, because I cannot encode `forall` typing constraints either, but I have accepted that.

Comment: @NicolBolas After consideration, I do not see how this is a duplicate. I am attempting to _abstract over_ common behavior for _existing_ types, not _require_ common behavior for _new_ types. Combined with the goal of `requires Monad<M>` instead of `requires Pure<M, A> && FlatMap<M, A, B> && FlatMap<M, B, C> && Pure<D> && FlatMap<M, C, D>` I cannot see how your suggested answer fits.

Comment: @Soren: "*I do not see how this is a duplicate*" Both questions are attempting to constrain a template on the basis of an open-ended constraint. You're both trying to constrain something based on an arbitrary set of types, based on properties of a template which don't exist until the template has been instantiated with its actual parameters. Which *includes* the type it is going to work with, and you cannot provide that template argument because you specifically want it to work without providing one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218246/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-soren).

Comment: What you want is not possible in C++, requirement cannot be expressed using quantifiers, and as classes can always be specialized, the fact that a member exists for a given template argument does not imply anything for other arguments.